# Approximating a power of a root of unity to within $\delta$

Tags: complex-numbers, approximation, roots-of-unity

I have an estimate of $\omega$, a root of unity.  I'm really wondering how small the error (in the estimate), which I give as $\epsilon$, has to be, so that when I take my estimate of omega to the power $\alpha$, it is still as close as $\delta$ to the actual value of $\omega^\alpha$.

If we have an $n$th root of unity, as:

$$\omega = e^{2 \pi i / n}$$

...and we want an approximation of $\omega$, as:

$$\omega_{\text{approx}} = \omega + \epsilon$$

...such that

$$\left| \Re \left( \left(\omega_{\text{approx}} \right)^\alpha - \omega^\alpha \right) \right| < \delta$$

...and

$$\left| \Im \left( \left(\omega_{\text{approx}} \right)^\alpha - \omega^\alpha \right) \right| < \delta$$

Can we get $\epsilon$ in terms of $n$, $\omega$, $\alpha$, and $\delta$?

Comment: $\Im(|z|)=0$ for all $z$. Maybe you didn't mean to put in the absolute value signs?

Comment: @columbus8myhw:  Hmmm...  I adjusted the question to attempt to show that the error in the real and imaginary portions should be less than $\delta$.

Comment: $\Im(a-b)=\Im(a)-\Im(b)$, and similarly for $\Re$. Also, you don't need that $\frac{}i$ in the last inequality.

Comment: @columbus8myhw:  Thanks for the help and simplification!  I fixed the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. At the moment, it seems that $\omega_{\rm approx} = \omega$ satisfies everything you want. Surely that's not what you intend....

Comment: @GregMartin:  I probably should have included an English description, which I'll give here and edit into the question.  So I have an estimate of $\omega$, a root of unity.  I'm really wondering how small the error (in the estimate), which I give as $\epsilon$, has to be, so that when I take my estimate of omega to the power $\alpha$, it is still as close as $\delta$ to the actual value of $\omega^\alpha$.

Comment: @GregMartin I think he wants the maximum possible value of $\epsilon$.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Columbus8myhw is right.

Comment: Ok, well, $\epsilon$ is going to be roughly $\delta$ divided by the derivative of the function $f(z)=z^\alpha$ evaluated at $z=\omega$. In this case, assuming $\alpha$ is a positive integer say, you'll get $\epsilon \approx \delta/\alpha$ suffices.

Comment: @GregMartin:  Your evaluation doesn't match up with my experimental results.  As I increase $\alpha$, $\epsilon$ increases, according to Mathematica 9.0.1.  This seems to go along with my intuition, too.  As I increase $\alpha$, the power that the approximation is raised to, intuition tells me that the error (or $\delta$) should increase since I'm raising $(\omega + \epsilon)$ to a higher power.  Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I agree that the error increases as $\alpha$ increases. But the error is $\delta$, not $\epsilon$. So as $\alpha$ increases: if you hold $\epsilon$ fixed, then $\delta$ will indeed increase. But if you hold $\delta$ fixed (as I thought you were asking), then $\epsilon$ needs to decrease to compensate.

Comment: @GregMartin:  I'm sorry - you are correct - and I am holding $\delta$ fixed.  If you give the details of your analysis, I can't think of why I wouldn't upvote it.  I _am_ still looking for a solid upper bounds of $\epsilon$ - I really need to know how large it can be - so I'm not sure I'd accept an answer that didn't give a solid upper bounds.  But again, you'd get the upvote, and it could be instructive.

Comment: Is there at least an upper bound on $\delta$, like $\delta \le 1$?

Comment: @GregMartin:  Indeed, $0 < \delta \ll 1$, i.e. you can assume $\delta$ is very close to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\alpha$ a positive integer and $0<\delta\le1$, set
$$
\epsilon=(1+\delta)^{1/\alpha}-1.
$$
We claim that if $|z-\omega|<\epsilon$, then $|z^\alpha-\omega^\alpha| < \delta$; in particular, the real and imaginary parts of that latter difference are both less than $\delta$.

To see this, consider the function
$$
f(z) = z^{\alpha-1} + z^{\alpha-2}\omega + \cdots + z\omega^{\alpha-2} + \omega^{\alpha-1},
$$
so that
$$
(z-\omega)f(z) = z^\alpha-\omega^\alpha.
$$
Therefore
$$
|z^\alpha-\omega^\alpha| = |z-\omega||f(z)| < \epsilon(|z|^{\alpha-1} + |z|^{\alpha-2}|\omega| + \cdots + |z||\omega|^{\alpha-2} + |\omega|^{\alpha-1}).
$$
Note that $|\omega|=1$, while $|z|<1+\epsilon$ since $|z-\omega|<\epsilon$. Therefore
$$
|z^\alpha-\omega^\alpha| < \epsilon((1+\epsilon)^{\alpha-1} + (1+\epsilon)^{\alpha-2} + \cdots + (1+\epsilon) + 1) = (1+\epsilon)^\alpha-1 = \delta,
$$
as desired.